# Why can't I initialise static variables in initializer list?

Tags: c++, oop, static

I was trying to use the following code:

```
class Test 
{
private:
    static int x;
public:
    Test(int i) : x(i) {}
};
main()
{
    Test a(5);
}
```

But, then I got the error:

```
‘int Test::x’ is a static data member; it can only be initialized at its definition
```

What is wrong with the above implementation?

Comment: Because it makes no sense?

Comment: Note that you can initialize a static const integral at class level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you the problem pretty accurately.

The problem is that a static member has only one instance, regardless of how many instances of the class you happen to create. You only initialize it once, even if you create multiple instances of the class -- which means it can't be attached to the constructor.

```
class Test 
{
private:
    static int x;
public:

};

int Test::x = 1; // newly added

main()
{
    Test a;
}
```

In this case, it looks like you may not really want a static member variable at all though -- you're passing a value to initialize it when you create an instance of the class, which tends to indicate that you may just want a normal member variable:

```
class Test 
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Test(int i) : x(i) {}
};

main()
{
    Test a(5);
}
```

In this case, if you wanted a second instance of the object with a different value, you could do that:

```
main() { 
    Test a(5), b(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Static variables aren't part of the object - they're part of the class. That's why you can't initialize them along with the other members of the object.

Somewhere in a source file you need to provide a definition of the static variable, and you can put its initialization there:

```
int Test::x = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Class static variables must have storage, and may have initialization, outside the class body.  Like this:

```
class Test 
{
private:
    static int x;
public:
    Test(int i) { x = i; }
};
int Test::x = 42;

main()
{
    Test a(5);
}
```